# How does bazel detect the mingw location on Windows?

Tags: mingw, bazel

I'm trying to persuade bazel to use the mingw32 toolchain on Windows. There isn't a stock toolchain definition for this, so I'm trying to make my own.

I've found the mingw64 toolchain definition in `local_config_cc/BUILD`:

```
cc_toolchain_config(
    name = "msys_x64_mingw",
    cpu = "x64_windows",
    compiler = "mingw-gcc",
    ...
    tool_paths = {"ar": "f:/msys64/mingw64/bin/ar",
        "compat-ld": "f:/msys64/mingw64/bin/compat-ld",
        "cpp": "f:/msys64/mingw64/bin/cpp",
        "dwp": "f:/msys64/mingw64/bin/dwp",
        "gcc": "f:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc",
        "gcov": "f:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcov",
        "ld": "f:/msys64/mingw64/bin/ld",
        "nm": "f:/msys64/mingw64/bin/nm",
        "objcopy": "f:/msys64/mingw64/bin/objcopy",
        "objdump": "f:/msys64/mingw64/bin/objdump",
        "strip": "f:/msys64/mingw64/bin/strip"},
    ...
)
```

However, these contain hard-coded paths to the mingw64 installation directory. Where do these come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Bazel-internal mechanisms call [cc_configure()](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/602b7cd1c6355822056331290299247b357fa50e/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl#L179), and from there it's normal Starlark. (It changes with bzlmod, but has the same effects downstream). That calls the [cc_autoconf](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/602b7cd1c6355822056331290299247b357fa50e/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl#L143) [repository rule](https://bazel.build/rules/repository_rules), whose implementation function ([cc_autoconf_impl](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/602b7cd1c6355822056331290299247b357fa50e/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl#L86)) has the start of the logic. It looks at the current operating system and some environment variables, and then calls one of several functions that actually generate a `cc_toolchain_config` invocation. In your case, that looks like it's [configure_windows_toolchain](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/602b7cd1c6355822056331290299247b357fa50e/tools/cpp/windows_cc_configure.bzl#L770). That's the function that generates those paths and substitutes them into a template.

If you want an easy way to change those paths, just copy the whole `local_config_cc` repository (aka folder) somewhere, edit it, and point [local_repository](https://bazel.build/reference/be/workspace#local_repository) at the result. You can use a relative path if you want to check that in next to your WORKSPACE too.

If you're looking for something more sophisticated, you can see if the logic in `configure_windows_toolchain` supports it. You can also write your own Starlark rule (based on `configure_windows_toolchain` or completely separate) that creates a similar `cc_toolchain_config`. For example, the bazel-toolchain project [calls cc_toolchain_config from unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl](https://github.com/grailbio/bazel-toolchain/blob/f14a8a5de8f7e98a011a52163d4855572c07a1a3/toolchain/cc_toolchain_config.bzl#L336).

Comment: Thanks --- I eventually found the code which does the autogeneration here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/602b7cd1c6355822056331290299247b357fa50e/tools/cpp/windows_cc_configure.bzl#L91 ...and the `mingw64` part of the path, which I need to change, is hard coded. I don't really want to copy the entire `local_config_cc` directory as there's rather a lot of it. It'd be really nice if the gcc-based Windows toolchains could honour the `CC` environment variable the way the Unix ones do...